# how should i export data to office documents and pdf in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation

i'm looking for the best way to tackle this issue and in what order we do it best.

we have an application where users can enter certain personal details,
afterwards they can download the word document (.docx) or get a pdf (.pdf) of their personal data.

what we already did is everything separate:
with a *.docx template, we fill the parameterized fields and then save it as docx to the user

and with a certain library called [**BioPdf**](http://www.biopdf.com/guide/dotnet_interface.php) we can convert the rendered word document into a pdf

we are looking to avoid having office installed (or any other office tool) on the server,
so the current library needs to go, we know of [**iTextSharp**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) as a library to create pdfs, but that would mean that every time the template changes, we need to update our *.docx template for the word files, and at the same time update the **iTextSharp** code that renders our pdf.

are we looking at this the wrong way?
in what order should we generate these files, in order to 
 - minimize the work when a template gets changed
 - have no office programs installed on the server

best regards
Sander Houttekier

Comment: I just noticed the following on CodeProject - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/WebPDF.aspx - it includes a demo iTextSharp app and may be of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as we still have not found a free library that does exactly what we need, we are seriously thinking of buying a license on [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) which does what we need with ease.

at least that is what the evaluation shows us ...

many of the suggested libraries can to some point generate the pdf with the data we need, but not in the style we want, we needed a system where we have template pdf files, to be filled some parameters, 1 of those parameters beeing a list of products each in its own table with a few rows of data on the product, and none of the above libraries gave sufficient support for that, either every table was on its own page, or the style of the tables needed to be created via the source code generating the pdf, while we had different templates this would have been hell to create code for each different style of each template.

so the quest for a free alternative of aspose continues, but for now i will close this one as we found a library that does what we want. (and if i look at the prices of aspose.words, i can only assume they know they are about the only providing these features :P)

Comment: You may also have a look at this [video tutorial](http://www.aspose.com/blogs/aspose-products/aspose-total-product-family/archive/2011/10/25/create-and-edit-documents-in-asp.net-mvc-applications-using-aspose.total-for-.net.html) to see how you can quickly integrate Aspose.Words for .NET with ASP.NET MVC. If you need any further help during the development, you may [contact our support team](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using the [OpenXml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en), which will allow you to create and manipulate office documents programatically.

It does not require you to have Microsoft Office installed or licensed on your server, just a single DLL that can be bin-deployed along with the rest of your application if you want.

I haven't played around with dynamic PDF generation (apart from good old GhostScript), so I can't offer any advice there.

Comment: openXml SDK is what we use for the docx generation, that works perfect and as expected, our only concern now was how do we get to a PDF in as minimal steps as necessary, starting from zero with itextsharp is harder than finding a library that goes from our docx to the pdf, but the latter (we found this BioPdf) required office on the server and that's not really an option at all.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... most of these PDF programs work the same way way as GhostScript: the document is opened in preview and printed using a generic postscript driver, and then the pdf is created from the postscript. So you need MS Office as a way to preiew the document. I believe that the itext approach gets around this by creating the document from scratch.

Comment: true, with itextsharp we can create pdf's from scratch without the office on the server requirement. I only hoped there was a similar system like itextsharp that works with an existing docx file or a similar template sytem. because after creating the docx with openXml SDK it seems weird having to re-create the whole file just for rendering a pdf of it. if that's the only option we'll just recreate it with itextsharp then

Answer (score 0):

You could have a try with [PDFSharp y MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/%28X%281%29S%285almgkadctq453l1mhhtcngk%29%29/Default.aspx)

It seems as the very same code can draw in a PDF, Printer or Screen.. and MigraDoc can render to RTF.

I had this scheduled to integrate with my projects but didn't try it myself, perhaps it fits your project.